# Advice For Creating POM Test Framework

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, page-objects, pom

I am developing a framework for the popular e-commerce trading website platform (Amazon) – from scratch. I will be starting a new automation testing role, and, I need to get more practice before I start. Hence, the need to develop the framework.

I have done some research. A Simple Google search for any previous “Conquistadors” - that had done this before was fruitful. Sample code for their previous exploration [on GitHub.](https://github.com/tjmaher/automate-amazon)

In addition, I  got some websites that I got more information from:

1. [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1013318/page-object-design-pattern)
2. Stephen's Guide To Selenium
3. The TrainLine

I intend to use the Page Object Model – for obvious reasons.
Does anyone have any advice regarding how I can approach this task?
Also, if you have any code – from a previous project that I can glean some ideas from, that will be great.

My plan is to write manual tests 1st (using different test techniques including +ve & -ve tests, state transition tests, Boundary Value Analysis, etc). Afterward, I will select easy,  straightforward tests & use them as my “smoke” tests (e.g login feature), then add more complex tests to build my framework.

Your ideas are welcome.